# How to make section in Nomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature

I try to make sections in Nomenclature and sort them as I desire in my paper like the one I added in the picture. I have not had any success. I am close to get mad! I searched a lot but I couldn't find any appropriate answer! Any help?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of getting mad, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an attempt with `nomencl` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Constants}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{V}}{\item[\textbf{Variables}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{sets}]}{}}}
}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
  \nomenclature[Cp]{$p_{Di}$}{Active power demand at bus $i$}
  \nomenclature[Vp]{$p_{Gi}$}{Active power generation at bus $i$}
  \nomenclature[SO]{$\Omega_{G}$}{Set of generator buses}
  Some text
  \printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `C` in `Cp` (`\nomenclature[Cp]{$p_{Di}$}{Active power demand at bus $i$}`) puts the entry in `Constants` where `Vp` would put it in `Variables`.

You have to compile with

```
pdflatex yourfilename
makeindex.exe -s nomencl.ist -t "yourfilename.nlg" -o "yourfilename.nls" "yourfilename.nlo"
pdflatex yourfilename
```

to get things done.

Comment: The package `glossaries` is more versatile for such jobs.

Comment: Thank You so much for your kind concern. That works for me! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help. I used this code:

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt with the `glossaries` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Nomenclature}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{Constants}
\newcommand*{\Bgroupname}{Variables}
\newcommand*{\Cgroupname}{Sets}

\newacronym[sort=a1]{APD}{$p_{D_{i}}$}{Active power demand at bus $i$}
\newacronym[sort=b1]{APG}{$p_{G_{i}}$}{Active power generation at bus $i$}
\newacronym[sort=b2]{RPG}{$q_{G_{i}}$}{Reactive power generation at bus $i$}
\newacronym[sort=c1]{SGB}{$\Omega_{G}$}{Set of generator buses}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

How it works.

First of all, I've defined a new glossary style `mystyle` to simulate the output of `nomencl`

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}
```

Then I defined three groups (`a`, `b` and `c`) which correspond to your "sections"

```
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{Constants}
\newcommand*{\Bgroupname}{Variables}
\newcommand*{\Cgroupname}{Sets}
```

When you want to define an entry, use something like

```
\newacronym[sort=b1]{APG}{$p_{G_{i}}$}{Active power generation at bus $i$}
```

where `sort=b1` means: insert the entry in the group `b` ("Variables") and put it in the list as the first element.