# IEEE nomenclature with very long table

Tags: longtable, glossaries, two-column, ieeetran, xtab

I am preparing a nomenclature for an IEEE two-column document.
I started from:

[How to make section in Nomenclature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223376/how-to-make-section-in-nomenclature)

Unfortunately, `longtable` does not work well in my case. Thus, I replaced it with `xtabular`. (I tried also `supertabular` but it works bad)

The output produced by `xtab` supplies the expected results but the compiler returns several error messages since `xtab` package defines many commands already defined by `glossaries`.

How can I solve this issue by preserving the same output?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xtab}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Nomenclature}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{xtabular}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{xtabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Cgroupname}{A1}
\newcommand*{\Vgroupname}{A2}
\newcommand*{\Tgroupname}{A3}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{A4}
\newcommand*{\Ugroupname}{A5}
\newcommand*{\Mgroupname}{A6}
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{A7}

\newacronym[sort=a1]{DTMC}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a1]{ROC}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a1]{MCC}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a2]{TP}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a2]{FN}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a2]{FP}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a2]{TN}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a3]{TPR}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=a3]{TNR}{A1}{A1}

\newacronym[sort=t1]{VMT}{$\mathcal{A1}$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=t2]{SE}{$\mathcal{A1}$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=t3]{BE}{$\mathcal{A1}$}{A1}

\newacronym[sort=s1]{OV}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=s2]{UV}{A1}{A1}

\newacronym[sort=u1]{b}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=u2]{t}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=u3]{trn}{A1}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=u4]{test}{A1}{A1}

\newacronym[sort=c1]{h}{$A1$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=c2]{l}{$A1$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=c3]{N}{$A1$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=c4]{S}{$A1$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=c4]{Beta}{$A1$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=c5]{Prob}{$A1\{\cdot\}$}{A1}

\newacronym[sort=m1]{Pi}{$\mathbf{A1}_{l}$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=m2]{Phi}{$\mathbf{A1}_{l}$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=m2]{P}{$\mathbf{A1}$}{A1}

\newacronym[sort=m1]{Zi}{$\mathbf{A1}$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=m1]{Xi}{$\mathbf{A1}$}{A1}
\newacronym[sort=m1]{Yi}{$\mathbf{A1}$}{A1}

\makeglossaries

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for IEEE Journals}
\author{John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        and~Roberto~Baggio,~\IEEEmembership{Senior Member,~IEEE}
        % <-this % stops a space
\thanks{J. Doe and R. Baggio are with the Department
of Engineering, University, Place, Calgary, 0000, USA \\ e-mail: [jdoe,rbaggio]@pasadena.com}% <-this % stops a space

\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised August 26, 2015.}}

\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Journals}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here. \lipsum[2-3]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
IEEE, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
s.
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE journal papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.8b and later.
\lipsum[2-8]

\section{Mathematical Background}

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!